# ERROR : Microsoft Visual c++ 14.0 required, thrown while pip installing Numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, numpy, pip

While pip installing numpy version 1.19.2 (via pycharm) below error is thrown

ERROR : Microsoft  Visual c++ 14.0 required

I have tried the workarounds given in the sites nothing seems to be working

Comment: It gives you a link in this error to go download Microsoft Visual C++. Have you tried following that link and installing it?

Comment: If you don't want to compile `numpy` from source you can download a wheel from Christoph Gohlke's site: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ . Be sure to download the exact binary you need for your version of Python and bitness. Then install using `pip install path\to\binary.whl` .

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not give any other info about the error, I assume that you have to install  Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0, which is part of Visual Studio Build tools, you can download the installer here: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools&rel=16 .

Then, click on modify, after that check the box inside Visual C++ build tools and finally modify

Here is an example:

[image]

If you already have visual studio tools installed you have to post the error message.